# Multiline descending order textbox

Tags: vb.net

How should I order descending lines in the textbox? can you little help.

```
12
14
7
19
21
22
4
13
```

That's.

```
Dim ValueHolder As Integer
For Each tb As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
    Dim txtboxvalue As Integer = CInt(tb.Text)
    If txtboxvalue > ValueHolder Then ValueHolder = txtboxvalue
Next
Label1.Text = ValueHolder
```

Comment: You're question and example here seem to be asking two seperate things? The example code will find the Maximum, not so much sorting.  Anyway, easiest way is to load your values into a collection like List(of Integer), then you can just use Linq expressions to do the sorting for you

Comment: The `TextBox` has a `Lines` property that returns a new `String` array.  You can process that array in any way you want, e,g, convert to numbers and sort, and then assign the resulting `String` array back to the same property.  That means that you need to research how to convert between a `String` array and an `Integer` array and back again and how to sort an `Integer` array.  Both very easy things to find.  Of course, a `TextBox` is a very poor choice for displaying sorted numbers, given that the user can enter anything they want.  You really ought to opt for something else, e.g. a `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the text into a 'datatable' and then use SQL-like commands to get the sorted data back to your multiline textbox.

Or you can try this other approach, which may not be the most effective/efficient, but it works.

First, add the next elements: 'datagridview','texbox' (multiline) and a 'button'.
Rename 'datagridview1' to 'dgv1'.
Add 1 column to 'dgv1' (PROPERTIES > COLUMNS).

Add this code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Reads every line in the multiline textbox and adds it to a new
    'row in dgv1
    For Each text As String In TextBox1.Lines
        dgv1.Rows.Add(text)
    Next

    'Sorts the dgv1
    dgv1.Sort(dgv1.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)

    'Clears the textbox
    TextBox1.Text = ""

    'Every row in the dgv1 (already sorted) will be copied back to textbox1
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv1.Rows
        TextBox1.Text += row.Cells(0).Value + System.Environment.NewLine
    Next

End Sub
```

Hope it helps